# How can I find the default gateway of a machine?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to find the default Gateway of a machine, but I see multiple interfaces.

Also, when I find my IP address from the below website, it gives me a different IP address. I thought the default Gateway and external IP would be the same? Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/whats-my-ip/
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.2.0.0        192.168.255.9   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.255.1   192.168.255.9   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun4
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun6
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun5
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun2
192.168.255.9   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.255.13  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun3
192.168.255.13  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
```

```
$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.2.0.0        192.168.255.5   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun6
192.168.33.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.255.1   192.168.255.5   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun6
192.168.255.5   *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun6
192.168.255.5   *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun3
192.168.255.5   *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun2
192.168.255.5   *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun4
192.168.255.9   *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun5
192.168.255.13  *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.255.13  *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`destination 0.0.0.0` and `genmask 0.0.0.0` matches any other packet which is not defined in routing tables (last way out), so your default gateway is: `10.0.2.2`.

You can also use:

```
$ ip r | grep ^def
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0  proto static  metric 100
```

> I thought the default Gateway and external ip will be same.

Not true, for example you can forward your traffic to your router with an internal IP address but your the router will replace the source address with its own public IP (NAT).

Comment: Or to get just the IP: `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3; exit}'`

Comment: To find out the default ipv6 gateway (or gateway6), use this command `ip -6 r | grep ^def`

Comment: `ip r` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**1st Method:**

`ip route show` or
`ip route` or
`ip r`

[image]

You will get some rows , the row where it says 'default' is the row that gives you information on default router ip.

To narrow down the result and finding/displaying only 'default' row you can filter it like this.

`ip r | grep ^def`

[image]

**2nd Method:**

`route -n`

[image]

Under `Gateway` column you can see your desired gateway ip.

**3rd Method:**

`netstat -rn`

[image]

Same as above, you can find your gateway ip under `Gateway` column.

**Result:** In my case, Gateway ip address is `192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pull down the network menu and select `Connection Information` and look at the gateway address there.

Otherwise, in `terminal` you can type `netstat -rn` and the first line which says default is where you'll see the gateway address.

Comment: `netstat -r` does not give default gateway address .. `netstat -rn` does